# How to specify rel property for a css file in a libraries.yml file?

Tags: drupal, less, drupal-8

So I'd like to specify a custom rel property for a css (well, less) file in my libraries.yml file in Drupal 8.

Would something like that possible?

```
base:
  version: VERSION
    css:
      theme:
        css/styles.less: { rel: stylesheet/less }
```

The resulting HTML would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/styles.less" media="all" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not shure but you can try this :

```
   base:
      version: VERSION
        css:
          theme:
            css/styles.less: 
               attributes:
                  rel: stylesheet/less
```

seen on : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#attributes

**EDIT**

Or try

```
 base:
      version: VERSION
        css:
          theme:
            css/styles.less: { rel: stylesheet/less }
```

or :

```
base:
 version: VERSION
    css:
      theme:
        css/styles.less: 
            attributes : { rel : stylesheet/less }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Still not working, and I tried many other combinations. I'll change it dynamically with jquery, as a temporary fix. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for correct answer. This is the one ;-)

```
library_name:
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.less: { attributes: { rel: stylesheet/less } }
```

Here is example for 'type' attribute

```
library_name:
  js:
    js/main.js: { attributes: { type: module } }
```